# How do I buy an Enterprise license?

Tags: magento-enterprise

I've posted on a couple of places on the magento site and I've left two messages on the voicemail for the 877 number. I have money available, I just can't figure out how to spend it.

Sorry for such a dopey question, but I just can't find anybody at home at Magento to speak to.

Comment: I sent a message to my Enterprise rep to contact you.

Comment: Uhm, ahem... No comment.

Comment: I can see your email because I'm a moderator but I prefer to have you contact me. See my answer below. And... sorry.

Comment: Turns out there was a sales conference and everybody was out. Since then things have been moving very quickly!

Comment: IMO not being contacted is unacceptable when you are trying to hand us thousands of dollars...

Comment: About 8 months ago I tried to contact Magento for some sales questions through their website and never got a call back or email response. I somehow got ahold of somebody after a few weeks and they claimed they never got the emails. Lame.

Comment: Yes, that is quite lame.

Answer (score 14):

:sadface:

Send me an email please: ben.marks@magento.com.

Answer (score 3):

This is so typical for all Magento EE related topics, but I always thought there is at least a reaction when it is about money. Glad CE is well community supported. Even big installations like gigaset.com are run on CE - no need to get On EE. Get a decent agency that supports you and you get custom modules worth many times than EE out oft the box modules that dont suite your needs.

Comment: What a brilliant observation. So the developers behind ongoing version increments of Magento can just eat their own source code for sustenance?

Someone clearly hasn't spent hundreds if not thousands of hours debugging extension conflicts caused by poor design (or code) or paying arm-and-leg rates for support from a 3rd party agency.

Comment: My observation clearly points out, that you don't get what you deserve by paying for an EE. That is all I am saying... the rest is happening in your mind. I would love to just tell our clients to give Magento Inc. their money, but being honest I simply cannot do this out of experience. I hope that Magento Inc. developers earn enough money indirectly via magento U courses, the developer certifications and/or the investments from the current owner (for eBay it seems to not having worked out that well) so that we all can enjoy upcoming versions of Magento. P.S: Don't try to eat source code!